# Difference between Celery and Scrapyd

Tags: python, celery, scrapyd

I have built a small scrapy spider using Portia. I have deployed it in the Scrapyd and working fine.

After searching i found that we can use Celery to schedule the spider.

Actually what is the difference between **Scrapyd** and **Celery**?

Can any one help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Those who down voted, Try to leave a comment ... Down voting wit out comment is pet peeve of mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) focused mainly on deploying scrapy spiders, while [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is a generic framework to run asynchronous tasks in a distributed and scalable manner.

You can do one with the other. but scrapy as you know is focusing on scraping the web, However with celery you will define your task.

**scrapy + scrapyd**: Scrapyd is build for scrapy, when you will "deploy" a new spider its kinda running `scrapy crawl myspider`. Scrapyd also provides a webservice to upload and start new spiders and some more features.

**scrapy + celery**: The celery task that you will need to implement will do basically the same things that are given in `scrapyd`. the main advantage in this way **IMO** is if you will eventually have requirements that scrapyd cant provide, it will be easier to implement them with celery, because in celery you define your own task.

From [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/):

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing.  It is focused on real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well.

From [Scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

> Scrapyd is an application for deploying and running Scrapy spiders. It enables you to deploy (upload) your projects and control their spiders using a JSON API.

Comment: Hi @udy, What is the advantage of using those in Scrapy. Meaning what whould be the diff between Scrapy + Scrapyd and Scrapy + celery

Comment: added a section about that in the answer, HTH